# How Can I get the Items of a category with its subcategory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two models for Category and subcategory.

The category model returns an array of data like

```
category = [ 
    {_id: '1', name: 'Appliances', slug: 'appliances'}, 
    {_id: '2', name: 'Computer', slug: 'computer'}, 
    {_id: '3', name: 'Phones', slug: 'phones'}, 
]
```

The subcategory model returns

```
subcategory = [
   { _id: '101', name: 'fridge', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '102', name: 'Radio', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '103', name: 'Apple', category: '3'}, 
   {_id: '105', name: 'Toshiba', category: '2'}, 
   {_id: '109', name: 'HP', category: '2'}, 
]
```

I want to return something that looks like this:

```
[
  {_id: '1', name: 'Appliances, subCategories: [
       { _id: '101', name: 'fridge', category: '1'}, 
       {_id: '102', name: 'Radio', category: '1'}, 
    ] 
  },
  {_id: '2', name: 'Computer, subCategories: [
       {_id: '105', name: 'Toshiba', category: '2'}, 
       {_id: '109', name: 'HP', category: '2'}, 

    ] 
  },
  {_id: '3', name: 'Computer, subCategories: [
       {_id: '103', name: 'Apple', category: '3'}, 
    ] 
  }
]
```

Here is the code i have so far

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
  const [subCategories, setSubCategories] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    loadSubCategories()
  }, [])


  const loadSubCategories = async () => {
    const res = await getAllSubCategories()
    setCategories(res.subCategory)
    setTotal(res.length)
  }


const getAllSubCategories = () => {
  return request('/subCategories', {
    method: 'GET',
  })
}
```

This only loads my subcategories tho. my category route is `/categories`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: A. You are not bringing the categories in your react code.
B. What db you are using? Your ORM should do this for you, you are not supposed to make this matching

Answer (score 2):

```js
category = [ 
    {_id: '1', name: 'Appliances', slug: 'appliances'}, 
    {_id: '2', name: 'Computer', slug: 'computer'}, 
    {_id: '3', name: 'Phones', slug: 'phones'}, 
]

subcategory = [
   { _id: '101', name: 'fridge', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '102', name: 'Radio', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '103', name: 'Apple', category: '3'}, 
   {_id: '105', name: 'Toshiba', category: '2'}, 
   {_id: '109', name: 'HP', category: '2'}, 
]

const result = category.map(e => {
    e.subCategories = subcategory.filter(a => a.category == e._id);
    return e;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const category = [ 
    {_id: '1', name: 'Appliances', slug: 'appliances'}, 
    {_id: '2', name: 'Computer', slug: 'computer'}, 
    {_id: '3', name: 'Phones', slug: 'phones'}, 
];

const subcategory = [
   { _id: '101', name: 'fridge', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '102', name: 'Radio', category: '1'}, 
   {_id: '103', name: 'Apple', category: '3'}, 
   {_id: '105', name: 'Toshiba', category: '2'}, 
   {_id: '109', name: 'HP', category: '2'}, 
];

const newCategoryArray = category.map(v => {
  const sub = [];
  subcategory.forEach(i => {
    if(i.category === v._id){
      sub.push(i);
    }
  })
  v.subcategory = sub;
  return v;
});
```

https://playcode.io/873264/